# Graph Colouring proof

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Prove that any (simple, undirected) graph $G = (V, E)$, with $m = |E|$ edges has chromatic number $χ(G) ≤\sqrt {2m} + 1$.

Could any please give me any hint about this question? I don’t know how to start it. Maybe induction?

Edit: I'd say they seem similar but it's hardly the same question

Comment: How is this a duplicate  question?

Comment: This is a duplicate question because you are supposed to be able to deduce $$x\leqslant1+\sqrt{2m}$$ from $$m\geqslant\tfrac12x(x-1)$$ Are you not?

Comment: Oh I see... my apologies.